# EF CodeFirst adding table to database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got ASP.NET MVC App with database added as Code First from Database. Now I need to create new table in datebase and add column in other. I've create it manually on database, now my question is how can I update database in Visual Studio project to show and allow me to use my created table? I've tried deleted all classes and connection string and add database again, but I've got exception:

```
"This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection."
```

Also helpfull will be information/link to tutorial how can I add a table from Visual Studio and sent changes to database.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are at the very beginning, I would follow this tutorial: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/setup-entity-framework-code-first-environment.aspx.  I found it to be excellent for Code First approaches.

Comment: Thank you for tutorial. After lecture I assume that it will be easier to create new project and new db in code-first convention, with first migration on empty base. Am I right? And could you tell me if I understand right that on every model change I lost all stored data cause base is dropped every time?